# How to extract list of XY coordinates found within a polygon?

Tags: coordinates

I have multiple polygon shapes covering the UK. How can I create an Excel spreadsheet of all 6 (sometimes 7) figure XY British National Grid northings/eastings that fall within these polygons?

I don't want just the XYs of the polygon verticies, but all coordinates intersecting the polygon.

Comment: why do you want **all** of them? Basically you need to scan across the rectangle defined by the polygon bounding box in metre steps and test to see if it the point is inside the polygon

Comment: You can't have 7 figure national grid references, that would be meaningless.

Comment: @Hornbydd not OS grid references- XY northing/eastings. In Northern Scotland you can get XYs like 353,269 East (X)  1,013,806 North (Y)

Comment: @IanTurton Because we need a list of all XYs to compare against incoming client orders. EG. a client will make an order with us, inputting details such as 123 Fake Street, XY: 125,456 523,366

Comment: just do a point in polygon when the points come in

Comment: @IanTurton It won't be done in GIS. The client orders are made online and queried against our database of postcodes. We want to move away from postcodes however and use their XYs instead. So I need to upload a list of all relevant XYs to our online database.

Comment: get a better database, there are literally millions of 1m squares in the UK

Comment: @IanTurton sure, there are millions in the UK, but not neccessarily under the polygons I'm looking at. Still, I do believe the dataset will be too large for Excel to handle.

Comment: can you add an example polygon to the question

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. You want me to upload a shapefile to the question? Or an image? I'm a newbie with stackexchange formatting.